# Struggling to understand how to get total orders by country for one month of an year from a schema

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table orders (id integer, country text, customer_id integer,
restaurant_id INTEGER, date date, order_value integer);
create table customers (id integer, name text, country text);
create table restaurants (id integer, name text, country text);
INSERT INTO orders (

id,
country,
customer_id,
restaurant_id,
date,
order_value)
VALUES
(1, 'Pakistan', 1, 1, '2021-01-01', 400),
(2, 'Pakistan', 2, 1, '2021-01-01', 500),
(3, 'Pakistan', 4, 2, '2021-01-01', 300),
(4, 'Pakistan', 4, 3, '2021-01-05', 200),
(5, 'Pakistan', 5, 4, '2021-01-01', 250),
(6, 'Pakistan', 4, 1, '2021-01-09', 266),
(7, 'Pakistan', 3, 2, '2021-01-07', 322),
(1, 'Holland', 1, 1, '2021-01-01', 378),
(8, 'Pakistan', 1, 3, '2021-06-01', 289),
(2, 'Holland', 1, 1, '2021-08-01', 480),
(9, 'Pakistan', 1, 1, '2021-03-01', 580),
(10, 'Pakistan', 3, 2, '2021-07-01', 360),
(3, 'Holland', 1, 1, '2021-09-01', 550),

(11, 'Pakistan', 4, 3, '2021-04-01', 991),
(12, 'Pakistan', 5, 1, '2021-04-01', 875),
(4, 'Holland', 1, 1, '2021-03-02', 250),
(13, 'Pakistan', 1, 1, '2021-08-01', 150),
(14, 'Pakistan', 1, 2, '2021-09-01', 290),
(5, 'Holland', 1, 1, '2021-07-01', 240),
(15, 'Pakistan', 1, 3, '2021-03-01', 780),
(16, 'Pakistan', 1, 4, '2021-06-01', 987),
(6, 'Holland', 1, 1, '2021-05-03', 457),
(17, 'Pakistan', 1, 4, '2021-05-04', 258);
```

The task is to extract the total number of orders of each country for January 2021. How am I supposed to get a rows with total orders of each country if I don't have orders column?

Answer (score 0):

First you exclude all data that are not in the selected year and month in a `WHERE` clause.

The rest is `GROUP BY` country

so you get

> ```
> SELECT
>     country,
>     MIN(DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y-%m')) Month_Year,
>     COUNT(*) Total_orders
> FROM 
>     orders
> WHERE YEAR(`date`)= 2021 AND MONTH(`date`)= 1
> GROUP BY country
> ```
>
> ```
> country  | Month_Year | Total_orders
> :------- | :--------- | -----------:
> Pakistan | 2021-01    |            7
> Holland  | 2021-01    |            1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     country,
>     COUNT(*) Total_orders
> FROM 
>     orders
> WHERE YEAR(`date`)= 2021 AND MONTH(`date`)= 1
> GROUP BY country
> ```
>
> ```
> country  | Total_orders
> :------- | -----------:
> Pakistan |            7
> Holland  |            1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ee36ffaf0ce1b8d88580a4fb13a324e)*

Comment: How do I hide the 'Month_Year' column?

Comment: remove it from the select

Comment: Can you break down this code for me? I'm having difficulty understanding how this code is getting executed.

Comment: the where clause removes all rows that are not in the month and year, so when you run the code without the group by and the count, you have 8 rows in total, with the countrys, the group by reduces the rows to distinct values and count counts the rows that have a distinct country name

Comment: 1. You didn't mention the table name on 'SELECT' and added the 'COUNTRY' column. Does this mean by not mentioning the table name, it selects all the rows of the country column in all the tables?

Comment: in my query i use the table `orders` which is after the `FROM` clause, the other tables aren't needed so i don't use them, ever join costs resources, that can be used elsewhere.

Comment: Once last question, Why use COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(date)??? why select all the rows  instead of selecting the column?

Comment: Count(*) counts all the rows incl. Doubles data would do the same, but you signalite with * that you want the absolute numbers , if you wanted to eliminate doubles you would write count(Distinct data) , so you it doesn't matter but no n 20 years or somebody else who reviews you works you want to know what idea you had at that time and so a*  would indicate care your intention